# how to check if column 1 item is present anywhere in the column 2

Tags: pandas, dataframe

```
index_names = result[            ((result['TotalPercent'])!= (result['TotalPercent2']))     ].index

result.drop(index_names, inplace = True)
```

above code checking only the 1st row with 1st row and 2nd rows with 2nd row like that....
But i want to check like, if all the rows in TotalPercent present anywhere in the TotalPercent2 is no then i want to drop the rows.

overal datafram shape is (15241,9)

Comment: Welcome to SO; please spend a minute to see how to properly format your code snippets (done it for you here). Plus, question has actually nothing to do with `machine-learning`, kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Comment: sorry .. i do that ..but this is  part of my ML project that is why i tag ML..

Comment: Please notice that the tags have to do only with the *content* of the question, not its context; the fact that you may be developing an ML system to be subsequently deployed, say, in a spaceship, does not qualify a question as being about `space-engineering`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

size=100

np.random.seed(42)

data = pd.DataFrame({'a': np.random.randint(low=0, high=100., size=size),
                     'b': np.random.randint(low=-500, high=500., size=size)})

for idx in range(len(data)):
    if data.loc[idx, 'a'] in data['b'].values:
        data.loc[idx, 'Check'] = 'Yes'
    else:
        data.loc[idx, 'Check'] = 'No'
```

Output:

```
     a    b Check
0   68   71    No
1   60  119    No
2   47 -496    No
3   18 -398    No
4    3 -305    No
..  ..  ...   ...
95  53  336    No
96  59 -401   Yes
97  96  301    No
98   7 -321    No
99  52 -278    No
```